# How to share bin folder between websites built in subfolders of the root domain in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

Specifically, I have many DevExpress assemblies that consume a lot of storage in my root bin folder. Using pointers, I have other websites running in subfolders of my primary site that have the same assemblies in a bin folder in the subdirectory.

I want to eliminate the bin folders in my subdirectory websites and have those sites reference the root `bin` folder.

How to do that without using GAC as I am using a hosting site and don't have access to the computer?